# How do we pass value or parameter from azure data factory to runbook and excute it

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-runbook

could you help me on how would we pass variable from azure datafactory to runbook.

for example i would pass the conatiner name for the run book to generate a sas key using the container name.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the requirement of generating an SAS token for an Azure storage container, you would have to use cmdlet [New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontainersastoken?view=azurermps-6.13.0) (that belongs to [Azure.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module) / cmdlet [New-AzStorageContainerSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-4.4.0) (that belongs to [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-4.4.0) module).

As instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.4.0), starting in December 2018, the Azure PowerShell Az module is in general release and is now the intended PowerShell module for interacting with Azure. So Az modules are latest recommended ones to use and AzureRM modules are the older ones. So AzureRM modules are the older ones and Az modules are latest recommended ones to use.

To make the cmdlet [New-AzStorageContainerSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-4.4.0) (that belongs to [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-4.4.0) module) work in your runbook, make sure you have [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-4.4.0) module imported / available in your Azure Automation account.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similarly, if your other requirements are related to Azure DataFactory then leverage [Az.DataFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/?view=azps-4.4.0) module cmdlets as appropriate. Note that, if necessary, you would have to [import required Azure modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules) or [update modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules) based on the cmdlets that you use.